# Some styled-components styles missing after create-react-app build

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app, styled-components

I have this big problem with my create-react-app. I am using styled-components and everything works whene developing but after I build it, some of the styled are missing and the app looks really broken.

It does not happen with the same component everytime. I tried it a month later when my app progressed a lot hoping the problem would solve itself, but it is still happening, just somewhere else.

I noticed that some styles are missing in head of the HTML - first style tag.

[image]

I don't know what to do with it, I haven't found anyone with similar problem.

Comment: After building it for the milionth time suddenly everything work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally solved the problem!

With `npm list styled-components` I found out that package `grid-styled` is using a different version of `styled-components` than my project. I synced the version and the styles started to behave correctly even in production build.